# Swapi get and render films in peopels card

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch, rendering

i need to render movie title from swapi.co in each people card

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState([]);
  const [films, setFilms] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchData('https://swapi.co/api/')
      .then(res => {
        fetchData(res.people).then(people => setPerson(people.results));
        fetchData(res.films).then(films => setFilms(films.results));
      });
  }, [])


  async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
};

  return(
    <>
      {person.map(item => ( 
        <div key={item.url}>{item.name}
          <ul>
            {item.films.map(el => (
              <li>
                {el}
            </li>
            ))}                    
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}

    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

i don't have idea how i should to do it because in render method  "item.films" return as arr with links to get. How i can change links to movie title?

Comment: `https://swapi.co/api/films/` returns a list of `films` and each one seems to contain a `title` prop. What are you missing then ?

Answer (score 0):

films.map() return all movie title in sequence.
I need to return only movie title when 
the character is present
for example when we get `https://swapi.co/api/people/1`
response is

```
"name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "hair_color": "blond",
    "skin_color": "fair",
    "eye_color": "blue",
    "birth_year": "19BBY",
    "gender": "male",
    "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
    "films": [
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
    ],
```

i want to change films links to films titile for each character

Comment: Then you will have to do new HTTP calls to the API for each film you want to fetch the title. (Also, use comments to answer previous comments)

Comment: I don't think anyone understands me that much. I have already feched everything and want to display titles instead of links. If Luke wasn't present in all parts of Star Wars, I can't render the map because it will display all parts in turn.


How do I change the person.films arrwhich are links to the appropriate titles from the films arr

Answer (score 0):

I know its late reply, but maybe it helps someone.
After fetching your character data, you need to map on character's films, and because they are links, you have to fetch every api to get the films and then extract the data you want from it.

[swapi-demo](https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-react-and-redux/displaying-a-characters-movies)